# dnf module install ignores provided artifacts

Tags: rpm, dnf

Unexpectedly, `dnf module install` wants to install a newer version of the requested package, ignoring the artifact shipped with the module stream.
As far as I know, this is exactly what should **not** happen with modularity?

```
Name             : duck
Stream           : 5.1000 [e] [a]
Version          : 2
Context          : duck-module-stream
Architecture     : 
Profiles         : everything
Default profiles : 
Repo             : dev
Summary          : DUMMY Module stream for `duck` and its dependencies DUMMY
Description      : duck's hallmarks are practicality and efficiency.
Requires         : 
Artifacts        : duck-0:84.3700.6-1.x86_64 

Hint: [d]efault, [e]nabled, [x]disabled, [i]nstalled, [a]ctive
[duck@duck ~]$ sudo dnf module install duck:5.1000/everything
Letzte Prüfung auf abgelaufene Metadaten: vor 0:00:15 am Mo 15 Aug 2022 10:30:04 CEST.
Abhängigkeiten sind aufgelöst.
=======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                         Architecture                         Version                                                                    Repository                                       Size
=======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Pakete der Gruppe/des Moduls werden installiert:                                                        duck-appstream                               1.9 M
 duck                                                            x86_64                               8.3900.10-1                                                                 duck-tools                                    87 M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is - nothing will prevent `dnf` to install the latest available rpm package in this scenario. The install is not bound to the stream artifacts, and if there is more repositories available containing versions of the requested package(s) they will be selected if their version is greater.

Think of module streams as virtual repositories. They provide a set of rpms, when `enabled`.

This is likely an issue when packages in a module stream are also available in non-modular repositories.